# Is the given sentence redundant or some kind of emphasis?

Tags: redundancy, emphasis

The below sentence is from one of a self-help book by IAN TUHOVSKY

> *Wouldn’t you have your own problems and your own life to worry about? Yeah, that’s right. People don’t even remember. They don’t care.**They couldn’t care less.***

He already mentioned ***"They don't care"*** then why it is followed by the sentence ***"They couldn't care less"*** which also has the same meaning ***"They don't care"***?

Is this some kind of emphasis? or that is redundant? or is my understanding incorrect?

And my mind says the second sentence exactly means *"They don't care **at all"*** but the first sentence is just *"They don't care"*. But I don't find any difference in these sentences, both looks same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is mostly for emphasis. ***They don't care*** and ***they couldn't care less*** are similar in meaning -- though not identical. The latter is more emphatic -- and it's also a very common phrase. (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/couldnt-care-less)

The author is trying to make a point that people don't even remember the problems you have. They don't care. They ***really*** don't care.

One could say it's a little redundant, but the author is very much trying to emphasize how unimportant your issues are to someone else. Repetition can be a form of emphasis.